# vue uploads a file to azure blob using axios, but the body value is not received from the back server

Tags: express, axios, azure-blob-storage

Help me

It is structured like this. In blob.js
In the blobName function, filed returns normally and req.body does not. I don't know why.

When transferring a file from the back server to ejs, the value of req.body is normally received.

Thanks

express
blob.js

```
const MulterAzureStorage = require('multer-blob-storage').MulterAzureStorage

const blobName = (req, file) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const publisher = req.body.publisher
  const grade = req.body.grade
  const subject = req.body.subject
  const version = req.body.version
  const stage = req.body.stage
  const check = req.body.container

let blobName = ''
 if (check === 'image') {
  blobName = publisher + '/' + grade + '/' + subject + '/' + 'version' + version
} else {
  blobName = publisher + '/' + grade + '/' + subject + '/' + version + '/' + 'stage_' + stage
}

  return blobName
}

const containerName = (req, file) => {
  console.log(req.body)
const containerName = req.body.container
  return containerName
}

const azureStorage = new MulterAzureStorage({
  connectionString: connectionString,
  accessKey: accessKey,
  accountName: accountName,
  containerName,
  blobName,
  containerAccessLevel: 'blob',
  urlExpirationTime: 60
})
const upload = multer({
  storage: azureStorage
})

router.post('/', upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('ok')
})
```

---

vue

```
            const fd = new FormData()
            fd.append('blobData', this.blobData, { type: '*/*' })
            fd.append('container', 'test')
            fd.append('publisher', publisher)
            fd.append('grade', this.grade)
            fd.append('subject', this.subject)
            fd.append('version', this.version)
            fd.append('stage', this.stage)

            await this.$store.dispatch('MANAGER_CREAT_BOOK', fd)
```

---

actions.js

```
     const MANAGER_CREAT_BOOK = async ({ commit }, box) => {
      console.log(box, 'action')
      await managerCreateBoook(box)
    }
```

---

api.js

```
      function managerCreateBoook (box) {
       
        return instanceAuth.post('api/blob', box, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the issue, we need to reverse the order of my form object properties in the front end. Because when the `multer` populate `req.body`, it may depend on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

For example
Vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="file" @change="uploadFile" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Upload</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    uploadFile(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files[0];
    },
    handleSubmit() {
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("container", "image");
      formData.append("publisher", "jim");
      formData.append("grade", "9");
      formData.append("version", "v1");
      formData.append("stage", "pub");
      formData.append("subject", "test");
      formData.append("file", this.file, { type: "*/*" });

      axios
        .post("", formData, {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.statusText);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
}
</style>
```

express upload

```
const blobName = (req, file) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const publisher = req.body.publisher;
  const grade = req.body.grade;
  const subject = req.body.subject;
  const version = req.body.version;
  const stage = req.body.stage;
  const check = req.body.container;

  let blobName = "";
  if (check === "image") {
    blobName =
      publisher + "/" + grade + "/" + subject + "/" + "version" + version;
  } else {
    blobName =
      publisher +
      "/" +
      grade +
      "/" +
      subject +
      "/" +
      version +
      "/" +
      "stage_" +
      stage;
  }
  console.log("The blob name :" + blobName);
  return blobName;
};

const containerName = (req, file) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const containerName = req.body.container;
  return containerName;
};

const azureStorage = new MulterAzureStorage({
  accessKey: accessKey,
  accountName: accountName,
  containerName,
  blobName,
  containerAccessLevel: "blob",
  urlExpirationTime: 60,
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: azureStorage,
});

router.post("/upload", upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("ok");
});
```

[image]
[image]